# Is there a elementary proof that $3$ is not a congruent number?

Tags: number-theory

How to show  that $3$ is not a [congruent number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number)?

I don't want to use [Tunnell's theorem(1982)](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~radko/circles/lib/data/Handout-336-378.pdf).

Is there a more elementary proof？Thanks a lot!

There is proof in Judith D. Sally's book "Roots to Research", but I don't have a copy...

Comment: It seems that Paul Monsky (1990). "Mock Heegner Points and Congruent Numbers". Mathematische Zeitschrift 204 (1): 45–67, deal with the case $p\equiv 3\pmod 8$, but I don't know which method he uses.

Comment: Sally's book quotes it from A. Genocchi, Note _analitiche sopra Tre Scritti_... Annali di Scienze Mat. e Fis. __6__ (1855), 273-317. The proof takes 2 pages, and splits into 4 cases. The non-trivial case uses that in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, the ideal $(3)$ is prime.

Comment: The book "Roots to Research" can be seen on Google books. Look at pp. 99--101.

Comment: en,  Thanks a lot

Comment: pp.1-26 can be seen on Google books

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is elementary to show that $n$ is not congruent iff the elliptic curve $E_n: y^2=x^3-n^2x$ has no non-trivial rational point. For $n=3$ it is not too difficult to show (I hope) that $E_3$ has rank zero (due to Genocci $1855$, without Tunnels result). There is a complete $2$-descent for the curves $E_p$ with $p$ an odd prime, which shows that the rank is zero if
$p\equiv 3 \mod 8$, see http://math.stanford.edu/~rhoades/FILES/EC.pdf, section $26.1$.

Comment: is there any chance you have a copy of the EC.pdf paper mentioned above, or know of a new location? The link given is no longer accessible (by me, at least).  Thanks.

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy I am sorry that the link is outdated. Fortunatey it is not difficult to find this result at other places (see the above comments).